# How to broadcast message with inline keyboard to all users in Bots.Business?

Tags: bots.business

How to broadcast message with inline keyboard to all users?

I have such code:

```
Bot.sendMessage("Hello")
```

I want:

- add inline Keyboard to that message
- broadcast it to all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command: "/message"

```
var message = "your text message"
var buttons = [
    {title: "Go to Google", url: "https://google.com"},
    {title: "Call command for Button1", command: "/touch Button1" },
    {title: "Call command for Button2", command: "/touch Button2" }
];

Bot.sendInlineKeyboard(buttons, message);
```

Command: /broadcast

```
// for admin only
if(user.telegramid!="your telegram id"){ return }

Bot.runAll({
  command: "/message"
})

Bot.sendMessage("message will be broadcasted to all chats")
```